# javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException Below Nougat

Tags: android, ssl, meteor, ddp

i am trying to connect my android client with Meteor Server.

code is successfully working on Devices above marshmallow.
but not working on marshmallow and below devices.

i am using [this](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client) library to connect my meteor Server

i am getting below error when i try below implementations on devices below nougat

> javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted:
>   ssl=0xb4067000: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
>   error:14077102:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unsupported
>   protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:740 0xabeeddd4:0x00000000)

```
            String exampleUri = "wss://myurl";
            WebSocketFactory webSocketFactory = new WebSocketFactory();
            webSocketFactory.setSocketFactory(new TLSSocketFactory());
            webSocketFactory.setVerifyHostname(false);
            WebSocket ws = webSocketFactory
                    .setConnectionTimeout(25000)
                    .createSocket(exampleUri)
                    .setPingInterval(20 * 1000)
                    .addListener(new WebSocketAdapter() {
                        // A text message arrived from the server.
                        public void onTextMessage(WebSocket websocket, String message) {
                            System.out.println(message);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(WebSocket websocket, WebSocketException cause) throws Exception {
                            super.onError(websocket, cause);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConnectError(WebSocket websocket, WebSocketException exception) throws Exception {
                            super.onConnectError(websocket, exception);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConnected(WebSocket websocket, Map<String, List<String>> headers) throws Exception {
                            super.onConnected(websocket, headers);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    Log.e("Connected", "true");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
            ws.clearProtocols();
            ws.connectAsynchronously();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

> TLSSocketFacory.java

```
public class TLSSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

    private SSLSocketFactory internalSSLSocketFactory;

    public TLSSocketFactory() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, null, null);
        internalSSLSocketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return internalSSLSocketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return internalSSLSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket());
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
    }

    private Socket enableTLSOnSocket(Socket socket) {
        if (socket != null && (socket instanceof SSLSocket)) {
            ((SSLSocket) socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1.1","TLSv1.2"});
        }
        return socket;
    }
}
```

> any help would be highly appreaciated

Comment: Did you test it on an emulator or a physical device ? If an emulator try doing a cold boot or even create a fresh AVD and try out

Comment: i have tested on both devices. emulator and nexus 5 also but did not worked for me